# VueJS trigger an event when a field is in focus

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I have a password change page with VueJS, and I want to view the password policy only when the user clicks into the new password field.
The problem is that I can't find if the page is in focus..

```
<b-row>
  <b-col>
    <b-form-group id="newPasswrd" label="New Password" :state="statePassword">
      <b-input-group>
        <b-form-input id="newPassword" v-model="passwords.newPassword" ref="newPassword" placeholder="Passwort" type="password" maxlength="60" />
        <p class="password-description"  >Must be at least 8 characters and contain at least two of the following: Upper case, Lower case, special characters or numbers</p>            
      </b-input-group>
    </b-form-group>
  </b-col>
</b-row>
```

and this is what I have in the script part of the page for testing:

```
      if (this.$refs.newPassword.focus() == true) console.log("focus");
```

My plan is to ultimately put this line in a computed and attach a bool value to it to view/hide the text below the field depending on whether if it is in focus.
What happens is that I get nothing in the console when I trigger the method where this condition is written, but the focus comes to the field instead, which is not what I want.
what should I do to get a bool value if the field is in focus?

Comment: How about an onfocus event? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp

Comment: Try with `v-on:focus`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bind using `v-on` with the `native` modifier:

```
v-on:focus.native="onFocus"
```

[From a Core Member](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/1241)

[Binding Native Events to Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this with css only?

If you don't have to support IE11/Edge:

```
b-input-group:focus-within>p {
    display: block;
}
```

If you have to support IE11/Edge:

```
input:focus + p {
    display: block;
}
```

I would also recommend adding classes instead of the barebone elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom directive

[Sample from official vuejs docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html)

```
Vue.directive('focus', {
  // When the bound element is inserted into the DOM...
  inserted: function (el) {
    // Focus the element
    el.focus()
  }
})
```

Comment: The problem is to detect focus not to set it.

Comment: it's only sample for creating directives, you can change it as you want

Comment: That is a good first step, but it is still not a solution to the problem ;)